# Is it possible to enclose the just top 3 radio buttons inside one single box(border)

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Is it possible to enclose the just top 3 radio buttons inside one single box(border)?

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radClientPackageDeliveryMethod" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
    AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="Plain" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClientPackageDeliveryMethod") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Any">Both</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem >Email Only</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem >Print Only</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Portal">Invoicing Portal</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Generated HTML code-

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod" class="Plain" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$radClientPackageDeliveryMethod" value="Any" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$radClientPackageDeliveryMethod$0\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_0">Both</label></span></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$radClientPackageDeliveryMethod" value="Email Only" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$radClientPackageDeliveryMethod$1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_1">Email Only</label></span></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$radClientPackageDeliveryMethod" value="Print Only" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$radClientPackageDeliveryMethod$2\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_2">Print Only</label></span></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$radClientPackageDeliveryMethod" value="Portal" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_radClientPackageDeliveryMethod_3">Invoicing Portal</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Something like this-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

You have to drop the RB list, and use separate radio buttons.

And in fact, if you have "separate" code and actions for each choice, then you can have EACH choice its own code stub. (and that often is preferred as opposed to using say a index).

Or, you can wire up all button choices to ONE code stub.

so, this markup:

```
        <div style="border:solid 2px;width:120px">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Both" 
            GroupName="G1"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"
            /> <br />

        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Email Only" 
            GroupName="G1" 
            AutoPostBack="true"
            OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"
            /> <br />

        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="Print Only" 
            GroupName="G1" 
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"
            /> <br />

        </div>

        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" Text="Invoicing Portal" 
            GroupName="G1" 
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"
            /> <br />
```

And code behind:

```
    protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton RB = (RadioButton)sender;

        switch (RB.ID)
        {
            case "RadioButton1":
                // code here for 1
                Debug.Print($"Btn 1 - checked = {RB.Checked}");
                break;
            case "RadioButton2":
                // code here for 2
                Debug.Print($"Btn 2 - checked = {RB.Checked}");
                break;
            case "RadioButton3":
                // code here for 3
                Debug.Print($"Btn 3 - checked = {RB.Checked}");
                break;
            case "RadioButton4":
                // code here for 4
                Debug.Print($"Btn 4 - checked = {RB.Checked}");
                break;
        }
    }
```

and you get/see this:

[image]

So, you can "link" or make separate buttons behave as "one" radio button group and only one choice is allowed by using "GroupName" for each of the buttons.

I should point out in above code behind, the RB would have/result in  checked=true in all cases, since the trigger occurs when you select a RB, and the others de-select for you automatic.